# PHP transform a text to meta keywords

Tags: php, string, text, replace

I want to transform a given text like

> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit! Nam suscipit
>   | Auctor pellentesque."

to meta keywords in a page. For that I need to arrange the text and filter everything but the text (no punctuation).

All should be in lowercase and the words containing 3 or less characters should be left out. The final output should look like this:

> "lorem, ipsum, dolor, amet, consectetur, adipiscing, elit, suscipit,
>   auctor, pellentesque"

I have searched everywhere for a solution but since I am new to php it's almost like chinese to me.

Comment: So what have you tried yourself? str_word_count() might be a useful starting point, with an array_walk() to convert to lower-case, and array_filter() to trim out all words of 3 characters or less in length

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this helps!

```
// Set the phrase into an array
$keywords = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit! Nam suscipit | Auctor pellentesque"; 

// Remove all special characters to only leave alphanumeric characters (and whitespace)
$keywords = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\s]/', '', $keywords);

// Explode the phrase into an array, splitting by whitespace
$keywords = explode(' ', $keywords);


// Create an empty array to store keywords
$end = array();

// Loop through each keyword
foreach($keywords as $keyword){

   // Check that the keyword is greater than 3 characters long
   // If it is, add it to the $end array
   if(strlen($keyword)>3){ $end[] = strtolower($keyword); }
}

// Implode the $end array into a comma seperated list
echo implode(', ', $end);
```

Edit: Removed an extra parenthesis from the code which was causing an error

Comment: You've missed arguments order in `implode()`.

Comment: Thank you so much.. it worked. Sorry if my questions sounded stupid but I do learn a lot from what you guys are writing here..

Answer (score 2):

```
function getMetaString($string) {
    preg_match_all("/[a-z0-9\-]{4,}/i", $string, $output_array);

    if(is_array($output_array) && count($output_array[0])) {
        return strtolower(implode(',', $output_array[0]));
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}

$string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit! Nam suscipit | Auctor pellentesque.";

echo getMetaString($string); // Output: lorem,ipsum,dolor,amet,consectetur,adipiscing,elit,suscipit,auctor,pellentesque
```

**Used functions:**
[implode](http://php.net/manual/bg/function.implode.php), [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit! Nam suscipit | Auctor pellentesque.";
        preg_match_all('/\w{4,}/i', $text, $matches);
        $meta = join(',', $matches[0]);
        print_r('<pre>');
        print_r($meta);die();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit! Nam suscipit | Auctor pellentesque.';
$string = strtolower($string);
$meta   = array();
$words  = preg_split('/[^a-z]+/', $string);
foreach ($words as $word) {
    if (strlen($word) > 3) {
       $meta[] = $word;
    }
}

echo implode(', ', $meta);
```